Why do the two pointer arrays return different addresses?
In the following code, I thought that the two outputs were the same. But in fact they are not! In my computer, the first output is 0x6ffde0, while the latter output is 0x6ffdb0.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
    char *s1[] = { (char*)"flower",(char*)"flow",(char*)"flight" };
    cout << s<< endl; // 0x6ffde0
    cout << s1<< endl; // 0x6ffdb0
    return 0;
}


I tried to output the address of "flower" and (char*)"flower". The results are the same.
cout<<(int *)"flower"<<endl; // 0x488010
cout<<(int *)(char*)"flower"<<endl;// 0x488010

Can anyone explain this problem please?

s is a different variable than s1. So of course they are on different places in memory.
The second case is just printing the address of a constant string literal

Can you please explain why you think they should be the same in the first place?

s and s1 are two different array of pointers to strings (char *), that are initialized with pointers to some constant strings, so they have different storage. Then the compiler optimizer unifies the identical constant strings, so their addresses are the same.

You're not printing arr[0], but rather arr (aka `&arr[0] in most cases, including here).

(char*)"flower" isn't valid c++?

Can anyone explain this problem please? I think the biggest problem here is your assumptions.

@user12002570 Looks valid to me, as long as you don't write to it.

Why do you even care? This is not the way you should write C++ nowadays anyway, whenever you can avoid raw pointers and "C" style arrays (and specialy mixing them),
Use static constexpr std::array<std::string_view,3> f_words{"flower", "flow", flight"}.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.
As these two arrays
const char *s[] = {"flower","flow","flight"};
char *s1[] = { (char*)"flower",(char*)"flow",(char*)"flight" };

occupy different extents of memory then the addresses of their first elements are different.
In fact these two statements
cout << s<< endl; // 0x6ffde0
cout << s1<< endl; // 0x6ffdb0

are equivalent to
cout << &s[0]<< endl; // 0x6ffde0
cout << &s1[0]<< endl; // 0x6ffdb0

As for string literals as for example "flower" then it is in turn an array of the type const char[7] and occupies its own extent of memory. That is these three arrays s, s1, and "flower" occupy different extents of memory.

s1 and s2 are two distinct objects and hence occupy different(unique) addresses.
